# An error when trying to do key press event in C#

Tags: c#, events, keypress

I add a key press event

```
private void listView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        DeleteContact();
    }
}
```

The framework automatically creates the class for it:

```
this.listView.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.listView_KeyPress);
```

When compiling I get an error on `System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.listView_KeyPress)`

```
No overload for 'listView_KeyPress' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler'    D:\...\MainForm.Designer.cs
```

I would appreciate any helpful answer, thanks.

Comment: Do you have defined method listView_KeyPress in the class where you have: this.listView.KeyPress += .... ???

Comment: Remove that again.  You need the KeyDown event to recognize the Delete key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyPress` event needs the parameter `KeyPressEventArgs` instead of `KeyEventArgs`.

However the `KeyPress` event only gives you the character of the key you pressed. And the DELETE key has no character. Therefor you should use the event `KeyDown` instead, as this one is gives you the KeyCode instead:

```
this.listView.KeyDown+= new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.listView_KeyDown);

private void listView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        DeleteContact();
    }
}
```

Comment: KeyPressEventArgs does not contain KeyCode

Comment: @Mike, no but it contains KeyChar

Comment: can you please provide a simple example how to handle Delete with KeyChar?

Comment: @Mike in this case you need the keydown event instead. I am updating my answer, give me a second

Comment: Thanks, does the same hold for every possible button?

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyPressEventHandler` delegate expects the second parameter to be a `KeyPressEventArgs` object, not `KeyEventArgs`:

```
private void listView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

If you need to use information found in `KeyEventArgs`, you should instead use the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. If so, be aware that the `KeyDown` event can be raised several times, if the user keeps the key pressed.

Answer (score 0):

See 
[KeyPressEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void listView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

has to be changed to

```
private void listView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

Comment: KeyPressEventArgs does not contain KeyCode

Answer (score 0):

Your signature is wrong. The e parameter in your handler shoudl be `KeyPressEventArgs` not `KeyEventArgs`